# Including external js files in a js file

Tags: javascript

HI,

I have a javascript lib which has a.js,b.js,c.js files....My logic is in d.js...How do I refer to a.js,b.js,c.js files in d.js???

Is it possible to refer??

I tried using

`document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>');`

and

`<script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>`

I get error telling the variables are not defined and the functions(they are in external javascript files) are not defined

Thanks:)

Comment: Not enough information. And PLEASE write normal English. This is not an SMS service. `document.write` should work, you must however escape the end tag: `<\/script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can dynamically load Javascript files. This is a good link.
http://ntt.cc/2008/02/10/4-ways-to-dynamically-load-external-javascriptwith-source.html

However what I find more useful is to use PHP to render my javascript and in my php append all the javascript I need for a relevant page.

Answer (score 1):

yeah its possible to do it by using the DOM to add the js file to the head of the document.

```
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.language="Javascript";
    newScript.charset="ISO-8859-1";
    newScript.src = 'yourfile.js';
```

headID.appendChild(newScript);

Of course you then have to tell your current JS file that the one you added has loaded. I do that by declaring a JS function in the current JS file and then calling it at the end of the one that has been dynamically loaded

Comment: Problem is, you should halt code execution in d.js until a.js, b.js and c.js are loaded.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a way to tell the script the new one has loaded

Comment: Why not just use script loader which is already tested across different browsers, and has that features that you describe.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use third party tools like this in my place of work without going through crap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this js loader http://www.dustindiaz.com/scriptjs/ I find it very convenient.
It has feature to manage dependencies, so you can give rules in which order scripts load.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest merging all required files into a lib.js file. In addition to not causing problems with undefined variables, it also reduces the HTTP requests to 1 from 4.

Try using the [closure compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) to merge your code into a single file.